# How to specify the directory using python argparser?

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

In my python script,i need to read the input ".csv files" from the Input directory(/home/ubuntu/pythontraining/InputCsv) and store the result in two separate output directories i.e,StudentDetails(/home/ubuntu/pythontraining/StudentDetails) and FacultyDetails(/home/ubuntu/pythontraining/FacultyDetails).I want to specify the directory path as a command line arguments using argparser.Can someone help me how to specify the directory path as a command line arguments using python's argparser?

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("Input_directory")
parser.add_argument("Student_directory")
parser.add_argument("Faculty_directory")
```

Comment: Please check my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below example -

```
import argparse

def some_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some description')
    parser.add_argument('--input-dir', help='Input directory')
    parser.add_argument('--student-dir', help='Input Student directory')
    parser.add_argument('--faculty-dir', help='Input Faculty directory')
    return parser.parse_args()

def main():
    args = some_args()
    input_path = args.input_dir 
    student_path = args.student_dir
    faculty_path = args.faculty_dir
    print (input_path )    #prints your input_path which you passed
    print (student_path )    #prints your student_path which you passed
    print (faculty_path )    #prints your faculty_path which you passed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Command line argument to be as -

```
python foo.py --input-dir <some_arg> --student-dir <some_arg> --faculty-dir <some_arg>
```

***Reference***

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html